# Considering node.js asynchronous architecture, why doesn't push throw error when executed after array init function calls?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to Node.js and learning about the history of callbacks, Promises, and async/await. So far I have written some code that I expected to throw an error, but it works fine. I suppose I should be happy with that, but I'd like to fully understand when async/await needs to be used.

Here is my code:

```
const rooms = {};

function initRoom(roomId) {
    if (!rooms[roomId]) {
        rooms[roomId] = {};
        rooms[roomId].users = [];
        rooms[roomId].messages = [];
    }
}

initRoom('A');
initRoom('B');
rooms.A.users.push(1);
rooms.A.users.push(2);
rooms.B.users.push(3);
console.log(rooms);
```

I expected the first `push()` to throw an error, assuming that it would execute in the stack before the `initRoom()` function calls completed. Why doesn't it throw an error?

Comment: There is nothing in `initRoom()` that is asynchronous.  It's all synchronous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in `initRoom()` that is asynchronous.  It's all synchronous code.

The "asynchronous architecture" you refer to has to do with specific library operations in nodejs that have an asynchronous design.  These would be things such as disk operations or network operations.  Those all have an underlying native code implementation that allows them to be asynchronous.

Nothing in your `initRoom()` function is asynchronous or calls anything asynchronous.  Therefore, it is entirely synchronous and each line of code executes sequentially.

> but I'd like to fully understand when async/await needs to be used.

You use promises and optionally `async/await` when you have operations that are actually asynchronous (they execute in the background and notify of completion later).  You would not typically use them with purely synchronous code because they would only complicate the implementation and do not add any value if all the code is already synchronous.

> I expected the first push() to throw an error, assuming that it would execute in the stack before the initRoom() function calls completed.

`initRoom()` is not asynchronous and contains no asynchronous code.  When you call it, it runs each line in it sequentially before it returns and allows the next line of code after calling `initRoom()` to execute.